# Distributed app freezes when connecting to In-App-Purchase Manager

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, distributed, freeze

I am quite stumped right now - I released a new update for my puzzle game app few days ago, and I started getting reports that the game shuts down whenever the user tries to enter the store. The store connects to the InAppPurchaseManager, gets the list of all the IAPs, and opens up the store view.

In debugging mode, I had no problems, and it even passed the review without problem! And now the game is freezing on all the users who try to give me some money!!! :S Did anyone else run into this problem? My store was working fine in previous version. Only thing that I changed was I changed the items that could be purchased so I removed some and added some.

Also I noticed that whenever user tries to enter the store WITHOUT internet connection, it works fine. It only freezes when the user has the internet connection (very ironic...)
Any input or past experiences would be very much appreciated!!! Thank you for saving me from this insanity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - In itunesconnect, in the manage IAP section, I turned off the IAPs that were not being used anymore, but apparently my program was still trying to receive one of the IAPs that was not being used anymore from the IAPmanager, so it was not receiving the product and crashing. I think anyone running into same problem as me would be rare, but if you do, here it is :) happy coding!